# How to download/clone a new branch from my server git repository into an already created local git repository in my PC with Eclipse EGit

Tags: eclipse, git, eclipse-plugin, egit, git-clone

This is driving me crazy.

I created a git repository in a Linux server hosted by my hosting company.

I cloned it to a local copy using Eclipse EGit.

I then created a branch in the original git repository in the server.

How do I copy the branch to my local copy using Eclipse EGit?

When I open Git Repositories inside EGit I see:

```
- Local
-- master

- Remote Tracking
-- origin/development
-- origin/master
```

How can I get the origin/development in my local using EGit?

I know I could create a new clone, but I don't want to do that as I believe there must be a way to get only the new branch.

**Second question** - where is the pull command inside EGit? I was able to find the fetch command, but when I run it it says that there is nothing to fetch. The RefSpec is:

```
+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```

**Third question** - is there a way to process git commands from a command line inside Eclipse in my Windows system? I thought about trying to do a pull from a command line, but I can't find it in my local system.

Thank you.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Your fetch is up to date because you already have everything copied to your local repository.  A pull will merge `origin/development` into master, which isn't what you want.  You want to create a new branch with `origin/development` as the starting point.  I don't know how to do it with egit, but on the command line, you do:

```
git checkout -b development origin/development
```

Comment: thank you for the answer. I finally found out that I can't submit git command line instructions from EGit (at least I believe I can't). I downloaded Git for Windows and I should be able to execute the command you suggested. I will report back success or failure.

Comment: It does work. I have decided to stop using Egit menus to issue git commands. I am now using the command line exclusively. This way I don't have to guess how Egit is going to execute an action when I press a menu button. I simply type what I want in the command line and I know how it is going to respond. I am marking this question as answered. Thank you Karl.

Answer (score 23):

I've also been searching around some hours to find out how to get a remote branch in Eclipse EGit...

The solution is stated in [this Bugreport](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=341679). And it is really easy if you know how to do it - no need for using the command line version of git, which - even though it works in 99% of all cases - can be risky as I already had problems that it interfered with Eclipse and EGit.

**Just follow these steps:**

1. First make sure you have opened the EGit `Repository view`. If you haven't opened it already, go to "Window → Show View → Other..." and from there select "Git → Git Repositories".
2. In the `Repository view` choose "Branches → Remote Tracking". You should see your remote branches there already (example: `origin/new_feature`).
3. Right click on the remote branch you wish to have with your local branches. Choose "Create Branch..."
4. The default values should be OK. **Normally you should not change anything here.** Please note that you should **not** change the "Pull strategy" to something else than "Merge" if you don't know what you are doing. Otherwise pulling upstream changes might result in a loss of data.
5. Click on OK "**Finish**" and you are done :)

Comment: It's pretty bad that the plugin doesn't pick up and set the expected (for example "new_feature" but instead sets a random [in effect] alphanumeric name) making you think that this option is not what you want. :-(

Answer (score 4):

I have been facing the same problem, and here is how I solved it:

1. Open Git Perspective
2. First you must have the branch that you want to check out, in your repository under *Remote Tracking*. My problem was that I couldn't see the remote branch here, so in order to solve this - execute a *Pull* on the repository, and this command should get you all the branches under *Remote Tracking*
3. right click the (remote) Branch, Check Out, Check out as new local branch

Answer (score 2):

To get  other branches in  sts , if pull didn't  work then  try this 
Team >> Remote>> Cofigure fetch from upstream stream>Advanced>
Check branch  you  want  in  source ref:  >  then add spec